# Replace all spaces and newline when you have a ↵ symbol in your text variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace all space and newline in a textarea with a symbol.

In my html, I have a textarea as below:

```
<textarea name="messageToPost"  wrap="hard" id="messageToPost" class="form-control"
rows="5" placeholder="Your post description here"></textarea>
```

Then, I added Javascript to get the value of the text area.

I use this code to get the value of the textarea : `$("#messageToPost").val()`

Now, Lets get back on the browser, I typed the text below exactly in the textarea:

```
Test
New Line 
Again New Line
```

In my javascript, when I use Inpect element in chrome, I get this value

```
Test↵New line ↵Again New Line
```

I don't know why I get this symbol ↵.  I tried to use function replace to replace the  ↵ symbol but in vain.

Also I try to replace it with `/\s+/g`.

What I want to do is, replace all spaces in my textarea value using javascript with '%20' and new line with '%0A'

Comment: Try `val.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g).join("%0A")`

Comment: I typed as is below: 

test
new line test
Again New line

Used text.replace (/[\r\n\s]+/g, '%0A')

Output 
text = "test↵new line test↵Again New line"

Comment: I changed the regex. Perhaps you did not see that?